# DOMDocument cannot parse XML

Tags: php, zend-framework, feed, domdocument, zend-feed

I'm using `Zend_Feed_Atom` to get a feed from a website but I'm receiving this error:

Message:

> DOMDocument cannot parse XML: DOMDocument::loadXML()
>   [domdocument.loadxml]: xmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 827

I tried with another site and I had no error. I want to know why do I get an error with that particular page and what does this error mean. I have looked online and it says that is a problem with the encoding (Which I don't really understand).

my code is simple, its just

```
if($type_feed == "atom"){
    $nfeed = new Zend_Feed_Atom($address);  
}elseif($type_feed == "rss"){
    $nfeed= new Zend_Feed_RSS($address);
}
```

Any help would be awesome! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the feed is busted then it is busted, there is little we can do about that.

One method of getting around this is to use `@` to suppress the error.

```
if($type_feed == "atom"){
    $nfeed = @new Zend_Feed_Atom($address);  
}elseif($type_feed == "rss"){
    $nfeed= @new Zend_Feed_RSS($address);
}
```

Note that this is not ideal as it will suppress everything when `new` is called.

Comment: But for example, Google Reader picks up the feeds that are malformed, how do they do it? And I tried with @new and still getting error

Comment: Sorry mate, I am Jake, not Google. I have no idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.recover

> Proprietary. Enables recovery mode, i.e. trying to parse non-well formed documents. This attribute is not part of the DOM specification and is specific to libxml.

You can try:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->recover = true;
```

Also, take a look at my implementation: https://gitlab.com/DeepRSS/Reader/blob/a2723735ff3e3cdd7d85649c92d0115211ea9a0d/src/Core/Service/ZendReader/FeedParser.php#L99

Comment: It should be `$dom->recover = true;`